# Unity build deletes all files on desktop

Tags: windows, build, ubuntu-unity

I finished a Unity project and decided to build it. I clicked build and it told me to select a folder. I selected desktop and clicked build. After a few minutes my project was built, but all files on my desktop were deleted.
I looked in recycle bin but no files were there. Is there any way to recover these files, and why isn't there a warning when building a project?

Comment: Which files on your desktop were deleted exactly? If you set your project folder to your Desktop, then clear your project files, the expected outcome would be that the project’s output folder would be cleared.

Comment: Every file on my desktop was deleted. I thought that the project would make a folder containing all the files and the exe, but instead it cleared the desktop folder and put the files and exe there as well. There was no warning and I didn't clear project files.

Comment: Did you create a folder on your Desktop?  If you had done that then it would have only cleared that folder, regardless, the file(s) might be in the Recycle Bin.

Comment: Sadly the files aren't in bin. I now know to make a folder, although I do not know why unity does not warn you or make a folder itself.

Comment: File Recovery software should be used if the files are not in the Recycle Bin

Comment: And a lesson for the future: Desktop is NOT for storing files anyway.